# Slither errors in Openzeppelin's contracts-upgradeable

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Using openzeppelin's UUPS upgradeable proxy contracts results in the following slither error. Are they false positives or should I be concerned?

Enviornment:
"@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable": "^4.5.2",

```
$ slither .
'npx hardhat compile --force' running
hardhat solidity version 0.8.9
```

Error 1:

```
ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable._functionDelegateCall(address,bytes) (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable.sol#198-204) uses delegatecall to a input-controlled function id
    - (success,returndata) = target.delegatecall(data) (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable.sol#202)
Reference: https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Detector-Documentation#controlled-delegatecall
```

Error 2:

```
ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable._upgradeToAndCallUUPS(address,bytes,bool).slot (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable.sol#98) is a local variable never initialized
Reference: https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Detector-Documentation#uninitialized-local-variables
```

Error 3:

```
ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable._upgradeToAndCallUUPS(address,bytes,bool) (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable.sol#87-105) ignores return value by IERC1822ProxiableUpgradeable(newImplementation).proxiableUUID() (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable.sol#98-102)
ERC721Upgradeable._checkOnERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes) (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC721/ERC721Upgradeable.sol#393-414) ignores return value by IERC721ReceiverUpgradeable(to).onERC721Received(_msgSender(),from,tokenId,_data) (node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC721/ERC721Upgradeable.sol#400-410)
Reference: https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Detector-Documentation#unused-return
```

Answer (score 0):

No, slither often flags OpenZepplin contracts, because they often use low-level functions like delegatecall or use assembly to deal with the return data.

So it's fine just keep in mind that while slither is an amazing piece of software it can't detect everything correctly.